# Can I uninstall security updates for rooting?

Tags: rooting, samsung, updates

I want to root my Samsung device, but previously, I have installed some updates. From what I know, successful rooting depends on [security bugs in the firmware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_(Android)#Varieties):

> The process of rooting varies widely by device, but usually includes
>   exploiting one or more security bugs in the firmware of (i.e., in the
>   version of the Android OS installed on) the device.

But security updates are intended to fix security bugs and thus can prevent rooting or make it harder to perform. Is there a way to uninstall security updates to increase the probability of successful rooting?

Update:
Some information about my device:

```
Android Version: 5.1.1
Device Name: Samsung Galaxy J1 (2016)
Kernel Version: 3.10.9
```

Comment: There is an easier way: Just don't buy devices that can't be unlocked. Rooting via exploit is only needed on devices the manufacturer does not provide a way to unlock them. On an (bootloader) unlocked device you can simply install a custom recovery the using it root the device.

Answer (score 0):

What Updates did you previously install ?
What Android Version are you on ?
What Device are you using ?

Samsung has a feature called Knox that is literally the fort knox of Androids, Root abilities on Samsung device's are rare.

For your device, someone may have a specific method of unlocking the bootloader or even using ODIN to flash a pre-rooted firmware.

For a successful root, it mainly comes down to...

- Android Version
- Device Lock Status
- CPU Model
- OTA Updates installed

Each area can stop you from getting a successful root.

The usual method for Samsung device's is to use Odin and flash a custom recovery, then from that you would install SuperSU or Magisk.zip files.

I need more information to help you any further.

> Notes :
>      Samsung devices will not allow you to use some feature's on a rooted device... It is why many Samsung owners end up using custom firmware like Lineage ( A.k.a CyanogenMod )

Comment: I've updated the question with some info, I could found.

Comment: Updated New Separate Answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Here are some notes before you start :***

You may need to enable OEM unlock in the developer settings

> THIS WILL SET KNOX TO 1
>   I am not responsible for voiding your warranty with this, it's your choice.

---

**OK So to root....**

> 1. Download the PC USB drivers for your Phone
> 2. Download TWRP
>      download : extracted twrp.img ( not a mirror )
>      [TWRP 2.8.7.0 from XDA Extracted to .img](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1psEp98kfhcnxO4Tiq2o_hAhwcXeJd8A5&export=download)
> 3. Download Odin 3
>      [Odin 3.13.zip file download](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1Ym3qmAeojHHBw0_GanNDIXZiylmnufTz&export=download)
> 4. Turn off your phone
> 5. Boot into download mode
>      (Power + VOL down + Home)
> 6. In menu select continue
>      (VOL up)
> 7. Now connect your phone to your PC
> 8. Open Odin.
>      Make sure your device is recognized.
> 9. Click PDA on older Odin versions or AP on newer versions
> 10. Find TWRP
> 11. Click start and wait until it's done.
> 12. Reboot into recovery and have fun.

reference : [TWRP 2.8.7.0 - XDA Samsung Galaxy J1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/recovery-twrp-2-8-7-0-samsung-galaxy-j1-t3223994)

---

**After flashing TWRP**

- Download SuperSU.zip
  [SuperSU 2.8+.zip](https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1aGVWUIxB61G7pV9OR6DOsC2g4J3MYWwr&export=download)
- Place the SuperSU file on SD Card.
- Place the SD Card into the device.
- Reboot into TWRP 2.8+
- Flash SuperSU to gain root access.

---

**Want Full Root ?** ( not systemless )

- USE TWRP's inbuilt SuperSU installer to start with
- Then install SuperSU 2.8+ Zip file to force System Mode root.

---

**If this TWRP recovery is not for your model, please find the correct model and use the same guide, the process is the same.**